# What happens after calling close() of Androids Sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

There is a multiple of questions about when to close a Sqlite database. But before that the question is why should someone call that method. Since Sqlite is regarded as ACID-compliant there is no essential need to do that.

But for better understanding I want to know what happens after calling close() on a Android Sqlite database?

Answer (score 1):

The term *ACID-compliant* shouldn't be confused with the resources an open database connection holds to perform operations. Calling `close()` releases those resources occupied by SQLite database in Android. Once you call it, you can no longer read or write data using query, rawQuery, execSQL, etc.